# How to increase one's ojas capacity ?

Tags: yoga, spirituality, yoga-sutras

> The Yogis claim that of all the energies that are in the human body
>   the highest is what they call "Ojas". Now this Ojas is stored up in
>   the brain, and the more Ojas is in a man's head, the more powerful he
>   is, the more intellectual, the more spiritually strong.

How do one improve his ojas capacity ? How can one  measure his existing ojas level ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One can improve Ojas Shakti by transforming *Veerya* (semen) to Ojas by Spiritual Sadhana. [Sri Swami Sivanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sivananda_Saraswati) wrote many articles and books on this topic.

Swami Sivananda says the following in his article on [Practice of Brahmacharya](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1214).

> According to Yogic science, semen (Suklam or Sukram) exists in a
>   subtle form throughout the whole body. It is withdrawn and elaborated
>   into a gross form in the sex organ under the influence of the sexual
>   will and excitement. To be an Oordhvareta is not merely to prevent the
>   emission of gross semen already formed, but to prevent its formation
>   as gross seed and absorb it into the general system. The body of a man
>   who is a true Oordhvareta has the scent of the lotus. A chaste man in
>   whom the gross semen is formed, may, on the other hand, have the odour
>   of a goat. The semen dries up in those who practise Pranayama
>   seriously. The semen energy ascends up to the brain. It is stored up
>   as Ojas Sakti (spiritual energy) and comes back as Amrita or nectar.
>
> If the sexual energy is transmuted into Ojas or spiritual energy by
>   pure thoughts, it is called sex-sublimation in Western psychology.
>   Just as metals and chemicals are purified by heating, so also the
>   sexual energy is purified and changed into divine energy by spiritual
>   Sadhana, by entertaining sublime, soul-elevating thoughts of the Self
>   or Atman. In Yoga he is called an Oordhvareta in whom the seminal
>   energy has flown upwards into the brain as Ojas Shakti. There is no
>   possibility of the semen going downward through sexual excitement.

Normal people send semen outside through sex or copulation (downwards) but Yogis convert it Ojas Shakti and transform Sukshma or Subtle energy to brain (Upwards: as in Kundalini Yogi).

Swami Sivanada also wrote a book on [Practise of Brahmacharya](http://www.dlshq.org/download/brahmacharya.htm). He explains various methods and Science behind it in detail.

> Sexual impulses can, with difficulty, be controlled. A rebellion of
>   the sexual impulses takes place when you attempt to control them.
>   Constant Japa and meditation for a long period are necessary to direct
>   the sex energy into the spiritual channel. Complete sublimation of the
>   sexual energy into Ojas Sakti is necessary. Then only you are
>   perfectly safe. Then only you will be established in Samadhi, as
>   Rasasvad will entirely vanish. Extreme patience, constant vigilance,
>   perseverance and rigorous Sadhana are necessary to eradicate the
>   sexual impulses and attain perfect purity in thought, word and deed.

You can read the book for more details.

Swami Sivananda suggests constant thoughts on Lord, Nama Japa and various other methods, when an aspirant asked the same question, which is mentioned in his book [May i answer that?](http://www.dlshq.org/download/may_ianswer.htm).

> 43. Would you kindly suggest some effective methods for conversion and sublimation of the sexual energy into spiritual energy or Ojas?
>
> Observe strict continence in thought, word and deed. Give up thinking
>   useless and vain thoughts. Keep balance of mind in all conditions and
>   circumstances, contemplating the Divine. Practice Sirshasan,
>   Sarvangasan and Oordhva Padmasan, besides Viparitakarani Mudra.
>   Preserve the energy by constantly repeating the Name of the Lord,
>   doing intense Japa and meditation, and study of the Gita, the
>   Bhagavata, the Ramayana and the like. Develop Viveka, Vairagya and
>   Vichara. As dispassion increases, so is the vital energy not allowed
>   to leak out. The greater the Vairagya (non-attachment to worldly
>   objects) the more secure will be the semen. The more the preservation
>   of semen, the greater will be the transmutation into Ojas which means
>   abundant physical, mental, moral and spiritual strength and quick
>   evolution. Pranayam helps a lot in gaining control over the physical
>   machinery and the mind. To have control over the mind means to have
>   control over the Prana Sakti and prevent Veerya from being let out. To
>   have control over this masculine power means to have abundant Ojas
>   which enables the aspirant to glow spiritually. Intense Sadhana, with
>   the desires reduced to the barest minimum, will sublimate the sexual
>   energy into spiritual energy. For further information, go through my
>   book Practice of Brahmacharya. It gives exhaustive details regarding
>   the subject in question.

Comment: Any mantra is there to increase ojas?

Comment: @TatTvamAsi, the name of God is the most powerful mantra. Try the Hare Krishna Mahamantra, it will accomplish all of the above.

Answer (score 13):

The body has three subtle important elements viz ojas, tejas, and prana. Ojas is believed to be the last essence of semen. It is related to vigor and vitality. Ayurveda gives special importance to these three factors.

Ojas is the super-fine essence of kapha dosha associated with lunar cycles; it is therefore connected to regeneration. The qualities of ojas and kapha dosha are similar: liquid, sweet, and unctuous. Together they provide great support for the immune system and the reserves of life force.

Ojas can be increased by the combination of balanced diet, herbs, proper lifestyle, and yoga.

While building ojas it is also essential to avoid stress and other related factors. One should also focus on cleaning the system with processes like pancha-karma and then rejuvenating the body with rasayana and tonics.

**list of things that use up, diminish and deplete [ojas](http://baliayurveda.com/ojas-plus-10-potent-ways-increase/):**

Stress, anxiety, fear, worry, sorrow, and grief

Lack of sleep

Strong, bright, overpowering experiences and sensations

Excessive computer / television use

Loss of vital fluids (especially blood and semen)

Excessive sexual activity (for both sexes)

Use of drugs and stimulants (medical and recreational)

Excess, pretended and repressed emotions

Fasting

Lack of deep sleep, disturbed sleep

Devitalized food

Dwelling in unnatural environments

Overworking

Excessive exercising

Excess and/or incorrect meditation/breathing practices

Injuries

**[Increasing](https://www.banyanbotanicals.com/info/blog-the-banyan-insight/details/cultivating-juiciness-with-ayurveda) ojas:**

Honoring solar-lunar rhythms in one’s practice

Lunar and Sringara Rasa (visualizing the communion of opposite poles of the body) yoga and daily mantra, pranayama, mudra, and meditation
Nourishing the Heart Fire with love, sukha (intrinsic happiness), and santosha (contentment) in your life

Cultivating aesthetics, beauty, the arts, peaceful rhythm, and enjoyment of the art of living

Steadily following nourishing rhythms of dinacharya (daily routine) and rtucharya (seasonal routine)

Nutrition with organic cooked (for digestion), vegetarian food, not overly spiced

Organic dairy or nut milks if vegan (almond, cashew), ghee, fresh butter, small amounts of cream

Fresh nuts, honey, dates

Whole grains and rice

Fresh, sweet fruits and vegetables

Balancing sexual energy in accordance with the seasons and one’s constitution

Ayurvedic herbs and rasayanas—tonic drinks and jams like Chayvanprash

Making rasayanas with the guidance of an Ayurvedic counselor of herbs, including **Ashwagandha**, **Brahmi**, **Kumari** (Aloe), **Shankhapushpi**, **Shatavari**, Shilajit, and Licorice

Practicing various hatha yogic disciplines.

Comment: Your baliayurveda.com link is not working. Here is an archive of it - http://web.archive.org/web/20160709195708/baliayurveda.com/ojas-plus-10-potent-ways-increase/