# How to practice meditation to increase Ojas capacity?

Tags: yoga, meditation, yoga-sutras, bramhacharya, kriyayoga

The Yogis and many books like those of Sivananda swami say that practicing pranayam and meditation, one can become more ojasvi day by day. Coming to meditation, what and how should it be done ? There are many ways of meditations, but which is beneficial and best in achieving this state ?

Also, is kriya yoga to be considered meditation or pranayam and how to observe kriya yoga for a total beginner ?

Comment: Kriya is high level form ie raja or ashtanga yoga. You need a good master to start its practice and imitation.

Comment: The way is best answered by your guru.

Comment: first step is to be completely celibate (even in thought).. and to help that, avoid meat, alcohol & onion/garlic in foods, and avoid stimulating pictures in movies/internet. Sivananda was celibate, and only after practicing that for long, we can think about ojas & urdhva-rethas

Comment: Is is duplicate to [**How to increase one's ojas capacity ?**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18866/how-to-increase-ones-ojas-capacity)

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of meditations to choose from like stillness meditation, mindefullness meditation,Shambhavi meditation and SoHum meditation.
So far, the easy to practice and widely recommended one is sohum. But the thing about meditation is, try several methods till you find the toughest one to practise and stick to it. You will definitely reap rewards in the long run.
Kriya Yoga is just like any other yoga path such as Raja yoga,Bhakti yoga,Laya yoga, Jnana yoga etc.prepares the body mind and soul of the practitioner for spiritual enlightenment.
Kriya yoga essentially consists of Asana,Pranayama,Mundra,Bhanda and Dhyana. The most complete treatise on the subject is Swamy Satyananda Saraswati’s “Asana Pranayama Mudra Bandha”.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and can you tell me more about sambhavi meditation. Everywhere I've looked the instructions are unclear.

Comment: Please have a look at the following video link. The first two minute part of the video explains it.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Za2ZaBnrsnw